# Number of solutions for Ax=b over the finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

How do we find the number of possible solution for $Ax=b$ over a finite field $F_3=\{0,1,2\}$ or in general for $F_n$, provided $A$ is full rank and $b$ is also defined over the same finite field?

Would the answer differ if $A$ is $m \times n$ with:

1. $m=n$?
   I assume it would be the same in real case with one unique solution.

I am not sure of these cases: 
2. $m<n$ and 
3. $m>n$

Additionally, if there are any good resources for studying Linear Algebra over finite fields where I can read about this please do share.

EDIT: Comments answers the question, and clears my doubts. In case someone wants to add any of their perspective or list any resources for similar problems please share

Comment: You are using $n$ for two different things; let's say the field is $F_q$ instead. The same way as with equations over $\mathbb{R}$. If $A$ is of full rank, then if $m\geq n$ ($m$ equations in $n$ unknowns with no free variables) you get either $0$ or $1$ solution, depending on whether $b$ is in the columnspace of $A$; if $m\lt n$, then you have $n-r$ free variables, so you get $(n-r)^q$ solutions over the field of $q$ elements.

Comment: Hint: assume $Ax=b$ has one solution $x_{0}$. From Linear Algebra, we know that the set of all solutions for $Ax=b$ is $x_{0}+\ker (A)$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Hi @JohnnyElCurvas, Arturo Magidin thank you for both your answers. I understand it is like Ax=b have solution separated into two parts particular unique solution and a general solution. Combining them giving the final no of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be $0$ when $m>n$, because $A$ is not necessarily surjective.

If $m\le n$, as $A$ has full rank, there is at least one solution $x_0$.So the solutions are just $x_0+\ker(A)$ as commented, and the number of solutions is equal to the size of the kernel.

Since $A$ has full rank, by rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the kernal is $n-m$ and its cardinality is $q^{n-m}$. (In particular, when $n=m$, there is a unique solution.)

Now by the same logic, when $m>n$, there is either $1$ or $0$ solution as the kernel must be trivial since $A$ has full rank.